# Parallelize inner loops

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm pretty new to OpenMP, so I'm fine if I have this wrong. Also I wasn't successful in finding information about this but I'm sure I missed something obvious.

I have some nested loops, I would like to parallelize a certain way.

This is a sequential version. Notice `f(i)` is a larger integer between 100 and 100,000 roughly.

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < f(a); c++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < f(b); d++)
            {
                if (comp(c, d))
                {
                    result[a][b]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Naively, I came up with this method of parallelizing the code.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // Create a result_local array to avoid critical sections in the loop

    #pragma omp for collapse(2) schedule(guided) nowait
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < f(a); c++)
            {
                for (int d = 0; d < f(b); d++)
                {
                    if (comp(c, d))
                    {
                        result_local[a][b]++;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Add the result_local to result
}
```

This is the part where I'm not so sure. If my understanding is correct, OpenMP will not parallelize the `c` and `d` loops meaning each thread will execute a `c` loop in its entirety. Given `f(i)` can return relatively low numbers like 100 or relatively high numbers like 100,000, this means some of the threads might get stuck with a lot more work than other threads which is not ideal.

So then the question is how can I parallelize the inner loops to share the work better. I can't change `collapse(2)` to `collapse(4)` because the `c` and `d` loops iterate up to a number that is a function of the `a` and `b` variables.

I saw something in my research that maybe is helpful.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // Create a result_local array to avoid critical sections in the loop

    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
        {
            #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(guided)
            for (int c = 0; c < f(a); c++)
            {
                for (int d = 0; d < f(b); d++)
                {
                    if (comp(c, d))
                    {
                        result_local[a][b]++;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Add the result_local to result
}
```

Admittedly, I don't know enough to know if this helpful at all. What I saw indicates this might be parallelizing the `c` and `d` loops but leaving the `a` and `b` loops serial?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ok so you want to optimize a loop with up to `100,000 * 100,000 * 10 * 10 = 1,000,000,000,000` calls to `comp`? It seems *huge*, so not sure parallelism will be enough here. I am pretty sure there is a much faster sequential algorithm that can be designed. Can you tell us more about `comp` and `f`, or are they supposed to be generic?

Comment: I hadn't really thought about that when I posted. I also realized this morning (before I read your comment) that the number of calls to comp is kind of huge. I will be reevaluating to see about cutting back on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> omp will not parallelize the c and d loops meaning each thread will execute a c loop in its entirety.

This is correct.

> some of the threads might get stuck with a lot more work than other threads

You are right: the **work imbalance** between thread is a performance issue in the first code. A `schedule(dynamic)` help a bit to fix this, but there is not much more you can do on this version.

> I don't know enough to know if this helpful at all. What I saw indicates this might be parallelizing the c and d loops but leaving the a and b loops serial?

Technically, the `a` and `b` loops are executed in parallel too (since they are in a parallel section, but all the threads will completely execute all the iterations in lockstep (because the `omp parallel for` contains an implicit synchronization). You should not use a second `omp parallel`: regarding the runtime, this can created new threads 100 times, and even when no new threads are created, this result in an inefficient code (for example because of a bad default thread pinning). Moreover, `schedule(guided)` is not needed here and should be less efficient than a `schedule(static)`. Thus, use `omp for collapse(2) schedule(static)`.

> how can I parallelize the inner loops to share the work better.

The last code is not soo bad in term of work balancing although it introduces some unwanted overheads:

- The implicit synchronization of the `omp for` can be skipped using `nowait` since all threads are working on thread-private data.
- The access to `result_local[a][b]` can be replaced by a fast thread-private variable access.
- The conditional increment can be replaced by a branch-less boolean increment.
- `f(a)` and `f(b)` can be per-computed although optimizing compilers should already do this.
- When `f(a) * f(b)` is very small, this could be better not to execute the loop in parallel (because of the expensive cost to communicate between cores). However this is highly dependent of whether `cond` is expensive or not.
- When `f(a)` is big, there is no need to use a costly `collapse(2)` as there will be enough work for all threads (`collapse(2)` usually slow down the execution since compilers often generate a slow modulus instruction to find the value of the loop iterators at runtime).

Here is the resulting code tacking into account most fixes:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // Create a result_local array to avoid critical sections in the loop

    // Arbritrary threshold (this may not be optimal)
    const int threshold = 4 * omp_get_num_threads();

    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        const int c_lim = f(a);

        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
        {
            const int d_lim = f(b);
            int64_t local_sum = 0;

            if(c_lim < threshold)
            {
                #pragma omp for collapse(2) schedule(static) nowait
                for (int c = 0; c < c_lim; c++)
                    for (int d = 0; d < d_lim; d++)
                        local_sum += comp(c, d);
            }
            else
            {
                #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
                for (int c = 0; c < c_lim; c++)
                    for (int d = 0; d < d_lim; d++)
                        local_sum += comp(c, d);
            }

            result_local[a][b] += local_sum;
        }
    }

    // Add the result_local to result
}
```

Another more efficient strategy is to **redesign the sequential algorithm** to significantly reduce the amount of work.

---

### Redesigning of the algorithm

One can note that `comp(c, d)` is recomputed with the same value several times (up to 100 times) and the same for `result_local[a][b]++` or even `f(b)` (up to 1,000,000 times). In such cases, the generic solution is to **memoize the results** (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) for more information) to avoid expensive parts of the algorithm to be recomputed over and over.

Note that you cannot pre-compute all the needed `comp(a, b)` values: this solution would be too expensive in terms of memory usage (up to 10 Gio needed). Thus, the trick is to split the 2D space in **tiles**. Here is how the algorithm works:

- compute all the `f(a)` and `f(b)` sequentially (100 values);
- split the iteration space in tiles of reasonable size (eg. 100x100) and pre-compute all the required tiles that should be completely computed (possibly in parallel, although this is tedious);
- compute the sum of all `comp(a, b)` for each tile (i.e. for `a` in `[a_tile_begin;a_tile_end[` and `b` in `[b_tile_begin;b_tile_end[`) in parallel (each thread should work on several tiles) and write the sums in a shared array.
- compute the final result using the tile sums (partial tiles are computed on the fly in this last step) in parallel.

This algorithm is definitively *much more complex*, but it should be **up to 100 time faster** than the above one since most operations are computed only once.

Answer (score 2):

For your attempt of parallelizing the inner loops to have a chance to work, you need to do something about the data race to `result_local`:

- If you have enough memory for every thread to have it's own private version of `result_local`, you might be able to specify `reduction(+: result_local[:10][:10])` in the pragma, but I haven't used it with multidimensional arrays yet. You might have to use a linear array and "lexic indexing" (`idx = a * 10 + b`). If `result_local` is dynamically allocated (on the heap), this might be the better way of dealing with it anyway (better than some `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, due to cache locality).
- If `comp` is computationally intensive enough you might be better off by putting `#pragma omp atomic update` in front of `result_local[a][b]++`. This takes less memory. In your example with `a * b == 100` memory is probably not an issue.

As branching inside the innermost loop can be bad for performance, you might want to try out if `result_local[a][b] += comp(c, d);` gives better performance, as addition is quite cheap.